# Why is my footer not at the bottom of the page?

Tags: html, css

I have a page like http://codepen.io/meek/pen/NNprYb
My problem is that the footer is not staying at the bottom of the page, only at the bottom of the first section.

HTML for footer:

```
<footer class="row-footer">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">             
            text
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

and CSS:

```
footer {
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

No matter what I try I can't get it to stay at the bottom. I'd like for it to be at the very end of the contact section.

clarification: I don't want it to be fixed, I just want it to be at the very bottom of the page.

Comment: The footer on the bottom of the page is a common problem and can be solved using only CSS. Simply googling for "footer at the bottom CSS" or something similar will get you explanations and sample code.

Comment: @Edu I did google for multiple solutions, most of them suggested using position absolute which, as I explained, wasn't working. The other solution I found was to wrap all content in a wrapper div, which was killing the section's height. None of these solutions I found were good for me, hence me asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `height:100%` from `#content`

Remove `position:absolute` from `footer`

Setting the height to 100% will only make it as tall as the windows/screen height. Removing it will make it "auto-expand".

Comment: Oddly enough, this worked even without removing `height: 100%` from #content. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[Codepen Link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bpqmGx)

```
footer {
   width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

**OR**

just do the following 
Wrap the entire html inside a div lets call it wrapper 
then

```
footer{
  position: fixed;
  top:expression((0-(footer.offsetHeight)+(document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : document.body.clientHeight)+(ignoreMe = document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop))+'px');
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

This piece of code just calculates the top value of your footer div

Comment: I don't want it to be fixed.

Comment: Oh sorry you only needed to know why its happening ?

Comment: I need it to be at the very bottom of the page, under contact.

Comment: Oh okay got it so regarding the first thing do you want to know  why position absolute not working correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, using `position: absolute;` on footers is generally never a good idea since the footer no longer will move relative to the rest of the content on the site. I understand that you do not want to use `position: fixed;` since this will not give you the results you are looking for.

Your `#content` div currently has a constant height of `100%` which will push the footer to somewhere in the middle of the content.

My solution would be to use a `min-height: 100%;` on the `#content` div and remove the `position: absolute;` (and `bottom: 0;`) from the footer.

Result: The content-divs' height will adapt to be more than `100%` if more content is added. It will always be at least `100%` and therefore the footer will always be pushed to the bottom of the page, even if the content only fills half the window size.